# Unable to get Broadcast

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am unable to receive broadcast intent, although I have registered it . Can you please spot the error. Thank you very much. I tried with log messages, but it never reached onReceive() of broadcast receiver class.

Here is Class from which I send Broadcast

```
public class ServiceDemoActivity extends Activity {
Button startButton,stopButton,pauseButton;
final String musicIntentAction="com.CompetenceProject.Musicfilter";
Intent musicIntent=new Intent();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    stopButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Stopbutton);
    pauseButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Pausebutton);


   musicIntent.setAction(musicIntentAction);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("DEBUG", "Came to StartButton");
            musicIntent.putExtra("Message","start");
            sendBroadcast(musicIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "starBroadcaseSent",1000).show();

        }

    });
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("DEBUG", "Came to StopButton");
            musicIntent.putExtra("Message","stop");
            sendBroadcast(musicIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "stopBroadcaseSent",1000).show();
        }
    });

    pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.w("DEBUG", "Came to PauseButton");
            musicIntent.putExtra("Message","pause");
            sendBroadcast(musicIntent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "PauseBroadcaseSent",1000).show();
        }
    });


}
}
```

---

Here is Class that listens to broadcast:

```
  public class MusicBroadcsatListener extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.w("DEBUG", "Came to BroadCast OnRecieve");
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String res=extras.getString("Message");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Extra is "+res, 1000).show();
    Log.v("BroadCase","true");
    System.out.println("Broadcast came here");
    if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("start"))
        Toast.makeText(context, "start", 1000).show();

        else if(res.equalsIgnoreCase("pause")) 
            Toast.makeText(context, "pause", 1000).show();

        else if (res.equalsIgnoreCase("stop"))
            Toast.makeText(context, "stop", 1000).show();
    }
}
```

---

This is the Androidmanifest:

```
       <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".ServiceDemoActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <receiver android:name=".MusicBroadcsatListener" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.CompetenceProject.Musicfilter"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any errors (exceptions, closing window...) ?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is check this typo you have in your Manifest.xml file. I can't see the name of your receiver class here, but if its name has "broadcast" in it,  you spelled "broadcast" wrong -- "MusicBroadcsatListenter" -- in your manifest.xml file:

```
<receiver android:name=".MusicBroadcsatListener" android:enabled="true">
```

Comment: Sorry I checked it, its not the issue, both class name and Androidmanifest has same name -"MusicBroadcsatListener". Thank you for noticing though.

Answer (score 0):

To test, you have to execute the broadcast receiver before you execute the activity -- on the same device -- because the receiver needs to be running.  I'm not sure the best way to do this, but out of curiosity I copied and pasted your code into Eclipse into two separate projects -- one for the receiver and one for the activity. I executed the receiver project, then the activity project, and your code worked fine. If someone has a better way to test this, please post as I'd like to know too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by myself. I had put the receiver inside the activity tag. Thank you all for the support.